# Phonegap Camera Api won't work (failed to load resource)

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I'm using phonegap version 3.

I installed cordova and phonegap, but for some reason my console shows that phonegap.js and cordova.js fail to load. They are not in my js folder either so I thought that was pretty weird, but phonegap has always worked for me, until today when I tried to use their camera API function. I ran the plugin install commands for the camera and added this to my config.xml file:

```
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
</feature>
```

But the camera does not work in the iOS emulator nor does it work on the web browser. In the web console I'm getting these errors.

`Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server: file:///Users/thomas/dev/myapp/www/cordova.js`

and when I click on any of the buttons I get the error

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.camera.getPicture')`

Here is my code: (copied straight from the phonegap website)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Capture Photo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
      // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
      // console.log(imageData);

      // Get image handle
      //
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
      // Uncomment to view the image file URI
      // console.log(imageURI);

      // Get image handle
      //
      var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      largeImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      largeImage.src = imageURI;
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhoto() {
      // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhotoEdit() {
      // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function getPhoto(source) {
      // Retrieve image file location from specified source
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    //
    function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is missing the www folder correct structure.
Right now I am not on office to check the names exactly but:

```
<root_folder_name> / wwww
               index.html
                     /camera
                             index.html 
                  /plugins
                         /<camera plugin name>
                                               /test
                  /platform
                       /ios
                           /<projectname>.xcodeproj
```

or similar structure you should have. 
anyhow, from:
  `plugins / <camerapluginmane> /test/`  copy the `index.html` and the `camera` folder with another `index.html` to your root `www` folder.

Also need a `main.css` a `main.js` and a `cordova-incl.js` all files are at test folder.

Just double check the /test/index.html source and make that structure and files available at www root folder.

Tomorrow or Monday I can be in office to edit this answer and correct the names.

Your error: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.camera.getPicture'" it is at web part ( www structure) and the code calling didn't went to ios files ( .h .m )  yet!

I hope it helps!

Comment: in my plugins folder, all i have is an ios.json file

Comment: @Thomas as I can see doesn't worth to bother with your problem, Good luck

Comment: I ended up fixing it. I made a new app in phonegap, installed the camera plugin, and then copied my files over and it worked. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late to answer this question but there is no late for a working example. Below code worked for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

  <title>Camera Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value
    // Wait for Cordova to load
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
      pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
      destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }


    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved  
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
      // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
       console.log("  "+imageData);

      // Get image handle
      //
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
      // Uncomment to view the image file URI
     //  console.log("IMAGE PATH: "+imageURI);
      alert("Image Url : "+imageURI);
      // Get image handle
      //
      var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      largeImage.style.display = 'block';



      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      largeImage.src = imageURI;
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhoto() {
      // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhotoEdit() {
      // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function getPhoto(source) {
      // Retrieve image file location from specified source
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    //
    function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>  
<header class="header">
<div class="header-div">
  <div class="header-single">
    <span id="title">Details </span>
  </div>
</div>
</header>
<div class="clear">
</div>
<content class="content-style">
 <h2> Camera Demo</h2>

  <button class="demo-btn-style" onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
  <button class="demo-btn-style" onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
  <button class="demo-btn-style" onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
  <button class="demo-btn-style" onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
  Small image: <br>
  <img style="display:none;width:100px;height:100px;" id="smallImage" src="" /> <br>
  Large image: <br>
  <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" /> <br>

</content>

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

</boyd>
</html>
```

Comment: On Android I had to add to config.xml: <access origin="content:///*" /> even though <access origin="*" /> was already set

Answer (score 0):

In terminal, on my app's main folder, I ran `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera`. I had installed it on my browser using PhoneGap but I apparently needed to do this again to install it for the iOS version created by XCode.

`Plugin "cordova-plugin-camera" already installed on browser.
Installing "cordova-plugin-camera" for ios`

This added the .h and .m files to my platforms->ios->APPNAME->plugins folder.

It is all working now!